# Does adam optimizer not working well with one hot encoding vector?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I read in a website that said Adam optimizer have biased with 0 so does it has effect on one hot encoding vector dataset?

Comment: Uhm no, I think you have completely misunderstood or the website is misleading.

Comment: Can u enlighten me what the website mean?

Comment: What website are you talking about?